# input type file on IOS 8.1 cordova

Tags: ios, html, cordova, ionic-framework

I have used `<input type="file">` in my application. the problem is it works on my other device which has IOS 6.1 but when i try it on my IPad running IOS 8.1 the app crashes when I click on that file input !

Anybody having this issue ??

Thanks

Comment: Are you using the InAppBrowser? It sounds a lot like https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-7679 .

Comment: I solved it. I was building my application with xcode 5 . Now i am using Xcode 6 and vola its working ! @RoyS

Answer (score 0):

this work for me 
add to info.plist :

privacy - Photo Library Usage Description

privacy - Camera Library Usage Description

The problem was in the security of the xcode that does not allow the access to the camera and gallery if you do not specify so that you use them